# Datagridview shows classname instead of property

Tags: c#, class, datagridview, datasource

I'm trying to put data in a datagridview by putting a List as the datasource. This works great, however, nested classes are listed as shown on the screenshot. I'd like to show only 1 property of those classes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFRDD.png

Is there a way I can do this?
I don't really know what to search for..

Comment: Will you please add an example of how you are binding your data files to the columns?  Are you using AutoGenerateColumns, or defining columns specifically?  The solution you need is simple, but it will differ depending on on whether you're doing this in XAML, WinForms, or code.

Comment: nice server name ir1337.

Comment: Here is part of the listing.http://pastebin.com/hcxzmG1g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just override `ToString` to show what you need.

Unless you want editing, which will require more effort.

**Update:**

A simple solution (if you do not have 10's or 100's of these) is to create a proxy class.

Example:

```
class FooProxy
{
  Foo bar; // internal object

  public string Baz 
  {
    get {return bar.Baz; } 
    set { bar.Baz = value }
  }

  public bool Oink
  {
    get {return bar.Oink.Enabled; } 
    set {bar.Oink.Enabled = value; }
  }
}
```

Comment: In that case, it'll require more effort.

Comment: Is that Oink bool just an example or do I actually need to "enable" something? This got me confused.